# Inexperienced java user requesting advice with classes

Tags: java, class

I have created a class which sends a single datagram packet, which is successfully received by another program.

```
import java.net.*;

public class UDPServer {
    public static void main(final String args[]) throws Exception {
        final String sendID = "level1";
        final int val = 2;
        final DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(7474);
        byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
        final InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        final String sentence = sendID + new String(" ")
                + new Integer(val).toString();
        final String capitalizedSentence = sentence.toUpperCase();
        sendData = capitalizedSentence.getBytes();
        final DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData,
                sendData.length, IPAddress, 7470);
        serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
    }
}
```

My question is how could I run this code from another, passing on variables for `sendID` and `val`. This is eventually going to be sending information from a game to audio programming software, to create algorithmic scores.

Apologies if the code is wrong/badly formatted, I'm not a programmer by trade!

Thanks.

Comment: It's good that you're trying to learn Java, but Stack Overflow's not the best place to come to learn that stuff. This is more of a Q&A site, geared towards specific questions. You question is, essentially "How do I do Object Oriented Programming?". Maybe some other SO users will suggest good Java tutorial sites in the comments, but I expect you will see this question get closed as being too broad.

Comment: Create a method like : `public static void send(String sendID, int value)` and invoke it from other class as `UDPServer.send("level1",2);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Juste create a method Send with two parameters

```
public class UDPServer {
    public void send(final String sendID, final int val) throws Exception {

            final DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(7474);
            byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
            final InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            final String sentence = sendID + new String(" ")
                  + new Integer(val).toString();
            final String capitalizedSentence = sentence.toUpperCase();
            sendData = capitalizedSentence.getBytes();
            final DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData,
                  sendData.length, IPAddress, 7470);
            serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
     }
}
```

And now from another class

```
UDPServer server = new UDPServer();
server.send("level1", 2);
```

**Few comments on your code:**

Avoid using variable with the first letter in capital (i.e. IPAddress). Usually classes start with a capital letter, not variables.

You can simplify :

```
byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
sendData = capitalizedSentence.getBytes();
```

by

```
byte[] sendData = capitalizedSentence.getBytes();
```

and

```
final String sentence = sendID + new String(" ")
                  + new Integer(val).toString();
```

by

```
final String sentence = String.format("%s %d", sendID, val);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, works perfect. I am definitely going to have to rethink my approach, but seeing how this example works im pretty sure I can work it out and move forward. 

Thank you for the tips on formatting and simplification as well, always nice to be more streamlined!